# Best practice for splitting up a large object of data for lighter importing

Tags: javascript, object

I produce a large json file that contains an object with multiple config properties.  I plan on distributing it as a resource but i want to do it in the most size efficient way possible. The way it works now is the file that needs a config property imports the whole json file, and accesses it as `configs.config1`.

Please note that I am distributing this as a lib. One person suggested that I don't have to change the way I split the object because the user can just do clever things with webpack.  I cannot enforce that so I would like to handle this from the lib side.

These are the two ways i figured may make the most sense:

1. Split each configX into its own file 
   (i.e. `import config from 'config1.json';`)
2. Use a js file with multiple exports instead of a json file
   (i.e. `import { config1 } from 'configs'`)

I'm not sure which would be the most size efficient for the users to import.  *I need to add the least amount of weight to people's projects as possible.* If there's an even better option I'm not considering, please let me know!

JSON

```
{
config1: {...},
config2: {...},
config3: {...},
...
}
```

My current docs usage instruction:

```
import configs from 'configs.json';
var myConfig = configs.config1
```

Comment: Size should be the same for your two options and you can actually even combine both ideas by using an index.js in `configs` directory

Comment: If you have multiple named exports, the user of your library can always choose between `import * as config from 'config1.json';` and `import { config1 } from 'configs';`. I would recommend that style as it allows both.